# How do I change the taskbar icon in tkinter?

Tags: tkinter

[image]

So, I want to change the icon, that is displayed on the taskbar in tkinter, how do I do it?

PS I have Windows 11 if that matters
Thanks in advance

Comment: There are missing details to your question. It seems like you haven't compiled your code to an executive yet. Can you confirm? Did you do any attempt to change the icon yet? If so, please add your code related to this attempt. It's called a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are referring to the favicon in the title bar.

There is a method for the toplevel Tk widget. (Usually called `root` or `window`)

```py
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.iconbitmap(path_to_icon)
```